# How to find a variable type in python

Tags: arrays, types, python-3.9

I am new to python...

when I print something it prints 2 types of output for me.

Output 1:

```
 [('id', 'fs-idm205005536'), ('type', 'A')]
```

OutPut 2:

```
[('id', 'import-auto-t546'), ('data-mark-prefix', '('), ('data-mark-suffix', ')'), ('data-number-style', 'lower-alpha')]
```

Can anyone guide me on the type of the above output?

Is this an array? If it is an array how do I check whether the index contains the word "type"?

when i try like below i did not get proper output

```
Fruits =  [('id', 'testing'), ('type', 'A')]
key_to_lookup = 'id'
if key_to_lookup in Fruits:
  print "Key exists"
else:
  print "Key does not exist"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an array of tuple.

But anyway to check a type of a variable in python-3.8

```
>> x = [("id", "testing")]
>> print(type(x))
>> <class 'list'>
>> print(type(x[0]))
>> <class 'tuple'>
```

So to know if in the array there is a tuple with the key : 'id' you can do something like this.

```
fruits =  [("id", "testing"), ("type", "A")]
key_to_lookup = "id"
found = False

for fruit in fruits:
    if key_to_lookup in fruit:
        print("Key exists")
        found = True
if not found:
    print("Key does not exist")
```